# Exclude a package if DEBUG=True

Tags: python, django

If `DEBUG=True`, I want to exclude the package `storages`. How would I do this?

my settings.py:

```
if DEBUG:
    storages = ''

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app',
    storages,
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .
    'app',

if not DEBUG:
    # Add the package into installed app only if debug is false otherwise use installed apps without package `storages`.
    INSTALLED_APPS += ('storages', )
```